# Can't find the IP address of a Saslauthd login attempt

Tags: smtp, saslauthd

I need help locating the origin IP from this error messages/ login attempts:

From the 'sasl auth daemon' via Logwatch:

```
pam_unix(smtp:auth): check pass; user unknown
pam_unix(smtp:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty= ruser= rhost= 
pam_succeed_if(smtp:auth): error retrieving information about user whatEver
```

From `/var/log/messages`:

```
Mar  8 04:38:51 mySuperServer saslauthd[17397]: do_auth         : auth failure: [user= whatEver] [service=smtp] [realm=] [mech=pam] [reason=PAM auth error]
```

I know it's `saslauthd` related. They try to connect to the SMTP port to send email but they are rejected. I can't seem to find the IP address anywhere; I want to block it.

Comment: Look at the rest of the log entries.

Comment: i've checked but nothing there

Answer (score 0):

IP addresses for SASLAUTHD are logged in /var/log/mail.log

Answer (score 0):

The culprit might be that PAM related messages end up in another log file compared to mail system messages, such as postfix ones.

I've helped myself on my Debian system by merging the respective entries, and grep through the result.

```
cat /var/log/mail.log /var/log/auth.log |sort |egrep -B1 'saslauthd\[[0-9]+\]:[[:space:]]+: auth failure:'
```

This was providing enough context to see a single IP address probing for user/password pairs for me.